# How to call function instead of bind value in Ember.Select

Tags: ember.js

Can `Ember.Select` fire an action for `selectionBinding` rather than binding a value? I am looking to load JSON depending on the value of the select box, but `selectionBinding` is only binding a value, and not running a function. For example,

```
App.SettingsController = Em.Controller.extend({
    loadStartDates: function() {
                // Load dates from server
        }
  });
```

And my `Ember.Select` tag

```
{{view Ember.Select
    class="form-control"
    selectionBinding='loadStartDates'
    name="program_academic_year"
    id="program_academic_year"
    contentBinding="programAcademicYears"}}
```

Can I call a function in my controller rather than setting a value on change of the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ember.Select`'s `selectionBinding` must be bound to a value, but if you want to fire a functional when the select is changed all you need to do is observe that value.

```
App.SettingsController = Em.Controller.extend({
  loadStartDates: function() {
    // Load dates from server
  }.observes('selection')
});

{{view Ember.Select selectionBinding="selection"}}
```